# How to measure force against skin?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I would like to work on a science project which I will measure people how much pressure I have to put on a pressure point to start to hurt somebody. Is there a device which I can measure the pressure that I apply onto the person's skin?
Thank you!

Comment: We need more information. Pointed object like a needle or pencil VS s flat surface has a strong relationship to pain.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [load cell](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00R1J9DZ6) or a [digital scale](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004164SRA) to measure force. A lower accuracy [force-sensing resistor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00B887CLS) may be sufficient. If you simplify your test to vertical, gravitation force on a known mass may suffice.

As user8055 pointed out, you will need to make sure the area and shape of the end of the protrusion is constant in your testing.

Comment: This answer may mislead the OP.  Pain comes from a variety of insults - thermal mismatch,  gross pressure, skin penetration, etc.  Duration of force -- slow application vs.  impulse -- matters as well.

Comment: @Carl Witthoft, Good point. There are probably much more controllable experiments that could be chosen. I just gave some force measurement options. Everything else would have to be held constant.